# Function name not appearing in xcode 4.3.3 breadcrumbs pulldown

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I have dozens of functions across many .m files that appropriately show in the pulldown menu on the xcode bread crumbs bar. However, last night, I added a new function to my code, but it absolutely won't show up in the pulldown list. The function before it appears. The function after it appears. Pragma marks before and after it appear. I've restarted Xcode several times. After defining the function in the .h, Xcode autofills the function name in the .m. The code in the function works fine. It just won't appear in the breadcrumbs pulldown.

I'm getting around it right now by adding a pragma mark right before the function starts. But, does anyone have any suggestions on why it's not showing in the pulldown and what can be done about it?

Spr.h

```
-(void) wCheck:(NSMutableArray *)CO lat:(double)target_lat long:(double)target_long;
```

Spr.m

```
 #pragma mark wCheck <-- this works
 -(void) wCheck:(NSMutableArray *)CO lat:(double)target_lat long:(double)target_long
 {
      //the code in here works fine.
 }
```

Comment: I am guessing breadcrumb bar you are referring to is the Navigation bar. Also, would that function happen to be the first one in the .m file?

Comment: @Spectravideo328 - the function is pretty much right in the middle of the .m. Functions before and after it appear in the pulldown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

re-indexing didn't help. I'm just sticking with the workaround of adding a #pragma mark right before the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing re-indexing of your project. Open Organizer -> Projects, select your project, delete its derived data, restart Xcode, wait for it to complete indexing.